# Is sentence patterns used everywhere?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I am studying English in Korea.

All my friends and I are studying about 'sentence patterns'

Sentence patterns, said in here, are S+V, S+V+C, S+V+O, S+V+I.O+D.O, S+V+O+O.C.

But my teacher said these 5-sentence patterns are not perfect in grammar. But  because we don't use English by mother language, they will be helpful for understanding English.

Then, I came up with something.

Is sentence patterns used everywhere? (like U.S.A, U.K, Australia, anyother country where people use english by their mother language?)

I really wonder.

Comment: This is sound teaching : those patterns are pretty much canon in all 'Anglo' Englishes, as long as you restrict yourself to simple declarative sentences; and by the time you get to more complex structures you won't need the patterns to guide you any more.

Comment: These basic sentence patterns do not vary from one variety of English to another.  For example, a native speaker from any part of the world might say "The clerk sold me a ticket" (S+V+I.O+D.O).  Nobody would ever say "The clerk sold a ticket me" (S+V+D.O+I.O).

Comment: The difference between OP's 7 and your 10 is that your group distinguishes adjective and nominal realizations for what OP's group calls 'C' (complement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.towson.edu/ows/sentpatt.htm), there are 10 English sentence patterns. The English spoken in the U.S., the U.K., and Australia is — aside from some idiomatic language — mutually intelligible and founded on the same patterns. If you are able to speak and write using those patterns, you'll be just fine.

That said, consider that you wrote,

> Is sentence patterns used everywhere?

As "(sentence) patterns" is plural, "is" must also be plural. The correct question is, "Are sentence patterns used everywhere?" And to answer that question in one word, yes.