# Is there an English sentence 'equation' I can use?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence, sentence-patterns

I'm working on a chat-bot, however before I can do so, I need to understand the English language a lot better, in order to make the bot understand. Say I have 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog,' I have the adjectives quick, brown, and lazy, and two nouns, fox and dog. That makes a complete sentence, however how can I identify a sentence assuming I only know the structure of the English language, and punctuation, but not what the words are (yet)?

Alternatively, I COULD get a dictionary library to find the type of word each word is individually, and format it such as 'The ADJ ADJ NOUN VERB(past) over the ADJ NOUN' and go from there, however then I need to translate 'the' and 'over the' to a readable format.

Is there any type of English 'equation' for formatted sentences which I could use? Potentially in a RegEx expression of sorts?

Comment: Good luck. If you ever find a RegEx expression that completely encapsulates the English language, there's a chairmanship of a CompSci department waiting for you somewhere.

Comment: Study the problem for 10 years or so and you *might* figure something out.  If you're fairly literate in artificial intelligence.

Comment: "I have the adjectives quick, brown, and lazy, and two nouns, fox and dog. That makes a complete sentence". That's not true. It's also not the goal. Most people don't address chatbots with complete sentences, just as most people don't use search engines that way. Rather than approach this as an English exercise, have you looked at the tools available on AWS and elsewhere? This will show you the capabilities that already exist, and the weaknesses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is sentence patterns used everywhere?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259313/is-sentence-patterns-used-everywhere). (This is a Close-Vote template; the answers there (5 or 10 basic patterns) first of all assume that the term 'sentence' is well-defined. It isn't (some say that fragments may be classed as sentences, for instance, and some constructions are considered grammatical by less than 100% of articulate Anglophones). Also, sentences may theoretically be of infinite length.